# Change style of a certain position in Custom Expandable list view in Android

Tags: android, android-widget, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I implemented a custom expandable list view in *Android* with 5 group items. I want to change the style of a group item when I click it to expand.

For example, I want to change the font-style to italic to click to expand.

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks !

Comment: Posting code snippets is always the way to go! Also, try posting what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thanks for your look, I solved the problem by making my custom adapter class and calling the update function from the instance of the expandable list view.